# AngularJS : Scope value changing, but doesn't always apply ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on creating 'pretty' checkboxes and radio boxes in Angular. I have similar plugins developed in jQuery, but I'm having trouble with the Angular versions, specifically the checkbox.

What I've done is create a directive (prettyCheckbox) and its template is a div wrapping a checkbox input:

```
<div class="prettyCheckbox" ng-click="toggleCB($event)" ng-class="{ 'checked': checkbox }">
    <input id="{{inputID}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox">
</div>
```

As you can see, then the model value is checked, it changes the div class to checked, when its not, its not. The input is given a `display: none;` and it all looks good. When I designed it, I set it up to work with label's with a for attribute, and everything was ok.

Then I remembered you can also wrap an input with a label, and clicking that label should trigger the input. I tested my code on it, and it became super buggy. I saw the scope watch and console logs I had setup to see the variable be triggered 3 times for every one click on the div-checkbox, and twice when clicking the labels, and one of each of these times wouldn't actually change the value. It made no sense. I've between tweaking it for a bit now, and I have no idea what's the real issue, nor how to solve it. I'm hoping I can get some advice. I've created plunker with the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/OVzSUhqnLDpvtuiRh2sM?p=preview. Note that the plunker does make a bunch of console logs.

One of the most annoying inconsistencies is when I see the variable change but the ng-class doesn't trigger and change accordingly (when clicking on the label).

EDIT: Got the box changing via apply, but still no luck with the multiple clicks.

EDIT 2: I tried to modify it to get more answers about the double click, ended up tweaking it, and cleaned it up. I kind of get why clicking the checkbox in the second scenario (wrapped label) ended up clicking 3 times: clicking it also clicked the wrapping label, but that's still only 2 clicks. Donno where #3 comes from, but my solution seems to work. Here's a new plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vvIDSHshvsq1akvFpdUc?p=preview

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I see two logs for each click, one from line 28 and one from line 31, just as one would expect.  Running in plunker.com, on Chrome, with dev tools open to see the console.

Comment: Sorry, was slow to edit. Partial solution found, plunker updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are updating scope variable from the click event DOM, you need to tell angular to update binding via running the digest cycle. Currently in your case you are manipulating scope binding on `label.click` event, so inside that you need to run digest cycle using `scope.$apply()`

**Code**

```
label.click(function() {
   scope.toggleCB();
   scope.$apply()
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/COvSMJyEjfBPqRsvF6p2?p=preview)

Comment: This will update the visual of the pretty checkbox, but it doesn't solve the fact that the checkbox is changing back and forth multiple times per click. (Open the console to see this behavior)

Comment: Thanks! I completely neglected that since the label isn't part of the scope, it won't update without apply. But yah, still confused on why its double clicking. Any thoughts to that?

Comment: Actually, I figured out the why, thanks to your solution. The div is wrapped in the label. Clicking the div triggers its on click, plus the label click event. The `$event` should be stopping propagation, but its not, and that's the issue at hand. I modified the plunker slightly to show the fix (and clean it up), but still need to figure out propagation issue.

Comment: I think I got a possible fix, though don't totally understand why it broke: see Edit 2.

Comment: @RhoVisions I'll look at it in my night